# whats the solution of this error "Error at 16:53 Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation"?

Tags: pine-script

Syntax error at input 'end of the line without line continuation'

```
// Check for buy condition
buyCondition = candleBody >= 0.8 * (high - low) and
               candleVolume > sma(volume, 3) and
               close > open

// Check for sell condition
sellCondition = candleBody >= 0.8 * (high - low) and
                candleVolume > sma(volume, 3) and
                close < open
```

After 10 o'clock, if the green candle is 80% formed, and the volume of the last formed candle breaks the last 3 volume bars, then a buy up arrow should appear on next candle opening.
When a bearish reversal candle forms, the right sign symbol should appear.

if the red candle is 80% formed, and the volume of the last formed candle breaks the last 3 volume bars, then a sell down arrow should appear on next candle opening.
When a bullish reversal candle forms, the right sign symbol should appear.

give a stoploss settings from the buy or sell arrows.

stoploss will place when entry we entry made eigher its buy or sell.

and show entry and stoploss label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [line wrapping](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Script_structure.html#line-wrapping) issue.

> Wrapped lines must be indented with any number of spaces, provided
> it’s not a multiple of four (those boundaries are used to indent local
> blocks)

So change those blocks to:

```
// Check for buy condition
buyCondition = candleBody >= 0.8 * (high - low) and
                 candleVolume > sma(volume, 3) and
                 close > open

// Check for sell condition
sellCondition = candleBody >= 0.8 * (high - low) and
                 candleVolume > sma(volume, 3) and
                 close < open
```